# Complex MySQL sort

Tags: mysql, sorting

I've done an almost full re-write on this question as I'm still stuck... Looking for a way to view the data in a results table without having to use php or some other data interpreter/programming to see the results how I want to see them.

Basic results table is like this (jumble it up more, if you want):

```
 id1 |  id2 | name   | ord
 ------------------------------
 a1  | null | name1  |  0
 a2  | null | name2  |  1
 a3  | null | name3  |  2
 b1  |  a1  | name4  |  0
 b2  |  b1  | name5  |  0
 b3  |  a1  | name6  |  1
 b4  |  a1  | name7  |  2
 c1  |  a2  | name8  |  0
 c2  |  a2  | name9  |  1
 d1  |  a2  | name10 |  2
 d2  |  a2  | name11 |  3
 d3  |  a2  | name12 |  4
 d4  |  a3  | name13 |  0
 c3  |  d4  | name14 |  0
 c4  |  c3  | name15 |  1
 d5  |  b2  | name16 |  0
```

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
 id1 |  id2 | name   | ord
 -----------------------------
 a1  | null | name1  |  0  <--group header, signified by `id2` is null
 b1  |  a1  | name4  |  0  <--item that's parent to line below
 b2  |  b1  | name5  |  0  <--item that's parent to line below
 d5  |  b2  | name16 |  0  <--last child item
 b3  |  a1  | name6  |  1  <--special case where `ord` takes over
 b4  |  a1  | name7  |  2  <--`id2` is still the same, so `ord` sort
 a2  | null | name2  |  1  <--next group header
 c1  |  a2  | name8  |  0  <--`id2` is a2, so name2 is parent, `ord` sort
 c2  |  a2  | name9  |  1  <--same
 d1  |  a2  | name10 |  2  <--same
 d2  |  a2  | name11 |  3  <--same
 d3  |  a2  | name12 |  4  <--same
 a3  | null | name3  |  2  <--next group header
 d4  |  a3  | name13 |  0  <--`id2` is a3, so name3 is parent
 c3  |  d4  | name14 |  0  <--`id2` is d3, so name13 is parent
 c4  |  c3  | name15 |  1  <--`id2` is c3, so name14 is parent
```

**Wordy explanation of what I need**

Essentially, I need `id2` to be "group headers" that are sorted by `ord`. And then below each of them, I need the rows sorted in such a way that `id2` is equal to `id1` of the line above it and anytime `id2` is the same as `id2` for the line above it, it should sort by `ord`.

When it runs out of rows where `id2` matches the last `id1`, the next group header should come up and sorting should start over again with the next `id2` matching `id1` of the new group header.

Any item where `id2` is null is a group header, but in those groups, the `ord` starts over based on the "parent" line. Some of those lines are also parents to other items, thus the complex nature of the sort

There are other columns in the actual results table, so I simplified this down to the columns needed to actually do the sorting.

**Table data explained**

The actual `id` columns are char(36), `name` is varchar(1024), `ord` is int(11), and the other columns in the table run the gamut... I should also mention that these results are from a `JOIN` that's done for the purposes of limiting the results of the primary table where this data is found.

`id1` is the primary key and unique, doesn't really pertain to the sort order, except that the all rows with `id2` equal to a given `id1` group header should appear below it.
`id2` is a reference to a "parent line id" and thus why it's null for group headers; they're the parent-most lines and have their own sort order via `ord`.
`name` is actually item names expect for the group header rows which are categories names.

As an example, say the group headers are food groups and the other entries in are types of food. So one group header would be "fruit," the next "vegetables," etc. It's actually A/V gear, but fruit is probably easier to understand.

**What I've Done**

My attempts at this have been all over the map. I've tried various `order by`, `field()`, `if()`, and I've considered subqueries, but my skills just aren't up to hashing this out on my own. I think if I can get pointed in the right direction, I can handle combining what I have to get the right result. Unfortunately, out of frustration, I've deleted any semi-working code, but it was probably nothing more then an `ORDER BY` with a non-working `CASE` statement.

**Key Points:**

1. When `id2` is null, it's a group header and group headers should be sorted lowest to highest (0, 1, 2) by their `ord` field.
2. Any row that has `id1` equal to another row's `id2` is its parent. In other words, if a row is found where `id2` equals `id1` of another row, it should be placed beneath it.
3. If multiple rows exist where `id2` equals an `id1`, the sort should first consider #2, then sort by `ord` the lowest to highest.

Comment: This sounds like [hierarchical data](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). You may have to add some "left" and "right" columns into your data to make the ordering fast if it is.

Comment: that's probably a good way to look at it. that said, `id1` and `id2` would probably be my left/right and then `ord` would be the leaf nodes... thanks for this, I'll definitely take a look when time allows! if it turns out as a solution, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's been a while. Honestly, I've forgotten what this was meant to represent, but I *believe* I was trying to sort line items as they appear in an application. Assuming that was the case, I got an answer from one of our developers. We ended up using a combination of `COALESCE()` and `LPAD()`.

Say these were line items on a list, but some are nested and they all live in the same table. The only relation is knowing the parent line's `id` and an `ordinal`. We came up with this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', LPAD(COALESCE(item5.ordinal),4,'0'),`
   LPAD(COALESCE(item4.ordinal),4,'0'),
   LPAD(COALESCE(item3.ordinal),4,'0'),
   LPAD(COALESCE(item2.ordinal),4,'0'),
   LPAD(COALESCE(item.ordinal),4,'0')) AS line_order
FROM main_lines as main
LEFT JOIN sub_line as item on item.id = main.id
LEFT JOIN sub_line as item2 on item2.id = item.parent_line_id
LEFT JOIN sub_line as item3 on item3.id = item2.parent_line_id
LEFT JOIN sub_line as item4 on item4.id = item3.parent_line_id
LEFT JOIN sub_line as item5 on item5.id = item4.parent_line_id

ORDER BY line_order;
```

The `COALESCE` allowed us to null-safe the rows and the `LPAD` allowed the `CONCAT_WS` to provide a proper sort order and honor the 0's in each result.

Edit: Thanks to [Paul Maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067753/paul-maxwell) for the inspiration to prove this in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/209d45/1).

Answer (score 1):

The data you portray is hierarchial (id2 refers to a "parent") and in MySQL (up to at east 5.7) doesn't have specific features such as recursive CTE's to handle hierarchies. There are work arounds and here, where we appear to know the maximum number of levels we can use one left join for each (level - 1) (i.e. for 4 levels add 3 left joins). Once the hierarchy is established by the joins, then using COALESCE() across the various columns, many of which can now be NULL due to the left joins, we can arrange the data to suit the wanted sort order. *(Well "almost". If you compare the wanted order to the order shown by the query below there are some minor differences.)*

Please refer to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71945/1) also.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id1` varchar(2), `id2` varchar(4), `name` varchar(6), `ord` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id1`, `id2`, `name`, `ord`)
VALUES
    ('a1', NULL, 'name1', 0),
    ('a2', NULL, 'name2', 1),
    ('a3', NULL, 'name3', 2),
    ('b1', 'a1', 'name4', 0),
    ('b2', 'b1', 'name5', 0),
    ('b3', 'a1', 'name6', 1),
    ('b4', 'a1', 'name7', 2),
    ('c1', 'a2', 'name8', 0),
    ('c2', 'a2', 'name9', 1),
    ('d1', 'a2', 'name10', 2),
    ('d2', 'a2', 'name11', 3),
    ('d3', 'a2', 'name12', 4),
    ('d4', 'a3', 'name13', 0),
    ('c3', 'd4', 'name14', 0),
    ('c4', 'c3', 'name15', 1),
    ('d5', 'b2', 'name16', 0)
;
```

**Query**:

```
select
      coalesce(p1.id1, p2.id1, p3.id1, p4.id1) id1s
    , coalesce(p1.id2, p2.id2, p3.id2, p4.id2) id2s
    , coalesce(p1.name, p2.name, p3.name, p4.name) names
    , coalesce(p1.ord, p2.ord, p3.ord, p4.ord) ords
    #, coalesce(p4.id1, p3.id1, p2.id1, p1.id1) ord1
    #, coalesce(p4.id2, p3.id2, p2.id2, p1.id2) ord2
    #, coalesce(p4.ord, p3.ord, p2.ord, p1.ord) ord3
from        table1 p1
left join   table1 p2 on p1.id2 = p2.id1
left join   table1 p3 on p2.id2 = p3.id1 
left join   table1 p4 on p3.id2 = p4.id1 
order by
      coalesce(p4.id1, p3.id1, p2.id1, p1.id1)
    , coalesce(p4.id2, p3.id2, p2.id2, p1.id2)
    , coalesce(p4.ord, p3.ord, p2.ord, p1.ord)
    , id2s
```

**[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71945/1/0)**:

```
| id1s |   id2s |  names | ords |
|------|--------|--------|------|
|   a1 | (null) |  name1 |    0 |
|   b3 |     a1 |  name6 |    1 |
|   b4 |     a1 |  name7 |    2 |
|   b1 |     a1 |  name4 |    0 |
|   b2 |     b1 |  name5 |    0 |
|   d5 |     b2 | name16 |    0 |
|   a2 | (null) |  name2 |    1 |
|   d3 |     a2 | name12 |    4 |
|   c2 |     a2 |  name9 |    1 |
|   d1 |     a2 | name10 |    2 |
|   d2 |     a2 | name11 |    3 |
|   c1 |     a2 |  name8 |    0 |
|   a3 | (null) |  name3 |    2 |
|   d4 |     a3 | name13 |    0 |
|   c4 |     c3 | name15 |    1 |
|   c3 |     d4 | name14 |    0 |
```

**wanted**:

```
# id1 |  id2 | name   | ord
# -----------------------------
# a1  | null | name1  |  0  <--group header, signified by `id2` is null
# b1  |  a1  | name4  |  0  <--item that's parent to line below
# b2  |  b1  | name5  |  0  <--item that's parent to line below
# d5  |  b2  | name16 |  0  <--last child item
# b3  |  a1  | name6  |  1  <--special case where `ord` takes over
# b4  |  a1  | name7  |  2  <--`id2` is still the same, so `ord` sort
# a2  | null | name2  |  1  <--next group header
# c1  |  a2  | name8  |  0  <--`id2` is a2, so name2 is parent, `ord` sort
# c2  |  a2  | name9  |  1  <--same
# d1  |  a2  | name10 |  2  <--same
# d2  |  a2  | name11 |  3  <--same
# d3  |  a2  | name12 |  4  <--same
# a3  | null | name3  |  2  <--next group header
# d4  |  a3  | name13 |  0  <--`id2` is a3, so name3 is parent
# c3  |  d4  | name14 |  0  <--`id2` is d3, so name13 is parent
# c4  |  c3  | name15 |  1  <--`id2` is c3, so name14 is parent
```